# JavaScript get prototype of object

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I have:

```
var person = {
    kind: 'person'
};

// create new object specifying the prototype as person
var zack = Object.create( person );

console.log( Object.getPrototypeOf(zack) );
```

Output:
`Object {kind: "person"}`

Why does it not output `person`?

Comment: `Object.getPrototypeOf(zack) === person; // true`

Comment: It's not gonna output the variable name you assigned the object literal to

Comment: It's unclear to me what the problem is. It seems to exactly output the value of `person`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the prototype of an object by `Object.getPrototypeOf(zack)`, it returns you the prototype object which is obviously your `person` object:

[image]

Your prototype object potentially has properties you defined for it (`kind: "person"`). Both `person` object you defined and prototype object returned by the function are equivalent.

Try checking the equality, you'll realize both are equal.

```
alert(person === Object.getPrototypeOf(zack)); // true
```

Comment: Thanksssssssssssssssssa